# What are these words in the 1841 will of Elisha Strong?

Tags: united-states, palaeography, will, 1840s

I was able to read most of the words in Elisha Strong's 1841 will but not the two shown in red below.  My transcription includes:

> The Said Eunice Strong shall pay one third for the support & education
>   of Lucy Strong and Julia C Strong until they are eighteen years of age
>   and the remaining two thirds for their support to be paid out of the
>   remaining two thirds of the property in **??** and received by the others
>   heirs  I give and bequeath unto my eleven children Elisha N Strong William
>   Strong Moses D. Strong Jairus Strong Ira Strong William B Strong Wm
>   Strong Angeline Collins **??** Stonell Lucy Strong and Julia Strong all
>   the remaining two thirds of all my property

I realize it may be impossible to determine the daughter's name but am hopeful that someone can determine the earlier word.

[image: excerpt of will]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> The Said Eunice Strong shall pay one third for the support & education
>   of Lucy Strong and Julia C Strong until they are eighteen years of age
>   and the remaining two thirds for their support to be paid out of the
>   remaining two thirds of the property in **proportion as** received by
>   the others heirs I give and bequeath unto my eleven children Elisha N
>   Strong **Wilber** Strong Moses D. Strong Jairus Strong Ira Strong
>   William B Strong **John** Strong Angeline Collins **Densa Stowell**
>   Lucy Strong and Julia Strong all the remaining two thirds of all my
>   property

Densa appears in other records as Dency. For example, here is her entry on [FindAGrave](http://www.findagrave.com/cgi-bin/fg.cgi?page=gr&GRid=65824306).

Comment: Wow!  You did even more than I asked.  You're the best, vervet.